# gnome panel wont open and give "Failed to request name: the name already has an owner" warning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, gnome

when I enter gnome-panel in my terminal I get this warning and gnome panel doesnt open. it doesnt look like its running when I use htop. I tried rebooting but got the same warning. I can do some things with gnome-panel from the command line like add desktop shortcuts but I want to access the gui.

```
** (gnome-panel:5530): WARNING **: 14:55:55.477: Failed to request name: the name already has an owner
```

system specs-
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="18.04 LTS"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Question may be appropriate for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.